# Android studio create plugin to auto generate classes in Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, intellij-idea, bloc

I wanted to develop a plugin for my flutter project which build by android studio.
The plugin I wanted to develop is like https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12129-bloc to auto generate some of the classes.
I know I have to create this type of plugin from intellij IDE, but I could not found enough information to start my plugin development. Any source of information for this please?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [IntelliJ Platform SDK](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/welcome.html) documentation. Here is a corresponding page about Android Studio Plugin Development - https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/android-studio.html .